# StanfordNLP Default Model + Custom NER Model

Tags: stanford-nlp

How can I combine the default model provided by Stanford NLP(english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz) together with my custom model(ner-model.ser.gz)? I want to recognize Toyota as an 'PERS' entity and the rest of the sentence as the default 'O' entity. It must be recognised as a 'PERS' entity by the engine for later usages (Sentiment/Concept) by the StanfordNLP.

I've already trained the custom model by following the instructions in http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#a. I'm using the code as follows for the combination of classifiers:

```
        String serializedClassifier = "ner-model.ser.gz";
        String serializedClassifier2 = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
try {
        NERClassifierCombiner classifier = new NERClassifierCombiner(false,
                false, serializedClassifier, serializedClassifier2);
        String ss = "Toyota is not an organisation, it is a person's name.";
        System.out.println("---");
        List<List<CoreLabel>> out = classifier.classify(ss);
        for (List<CoreLabel> sentence : out) {
            for (CoreLabel word : sentence) {
                System.out.println(word.word() + '('
                        + word.get(AnswerAnnotation.class) + ')');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The result is as follows:

```
Toyota(PERS)
is(O)
not(PERS)
an(O)
organization(PERS)
,(O)
it(PERS)
is(O)
a(PERS)
person(O)
's(PERS)
name(O)
.(PERS)
```

If I was to use the default model(ner-model.ser.gz) only, I would get

```
Toyota(ORGANIZATION)
is(O)
not(O)
an(O)
organization(O)
,(O)
it(O)
is(O)
a(O)
person(O)
's(O)
name(O)
.(O)
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm also stuck in this problem,did you get any solution.Please share the procedure if u got any.

Comment: Hi there. Nope. I've got no solutions for this.

Comment: Is their any alternative approch to do this?

Comment: I do not know of any. Sorry that i cannot be of any help. Maybe other extraction engines could help.

Comment: @Christopher Manning  Can You please help here, I am also facing same problem above